# How can I make sure RequireJS in Magento 2 loads jQuery before loading other scripts? I found that nesting requires solves this

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, magento2

I'm trying to load a lazy loader plugin which requires jQuery to function.
If I write my script as such:

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "ScandiLazy",
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery('.category-products .lazy').lazy();
    });
```

I get:

```
"jquery.lazy.min.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined",
```

Followed by:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).lazy is not a function
```

which is an error through because jQuery is not loaded.

But if I nest the requires:

```
 require([ "jquery"], function ($) {
        require([ "ScandiLazy"], function ($) {
            jQuery('.category-products .lazy').lazy();
        });
    });
```

Then it works perfectly.

But it feels wrong to nest the requires in order to make it work, is this actually a correct way to do this?

If this is incorrect, what's a way to make absolute sure jQuery is loaded before the ScandiLazy lazy load plugin loads?

Answer (score 1):

`ScandiLazy` needs jQuery to work so you have to tell RequireJS to set `jQuery` as dependency for `ScandiLazy` using `shim` (more here https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). Quick example how to fix this:

```
requirejs.config({ // configure RequireJS first
    shim: {
        'path/to/ScandiLazy': ['jquery']
    }
});

require([ // load modules
    "jquery",
    "ScandiLazy",
], function ($) {
    jQuery('.category-products .lazy').lazy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way in M2 is to add this to `requirejs-config.js` of your module/theme

```
var config = {
    shim: {
        'ScandiLazy': ['jQuery']
    },
    map: {
        ...
    },
};
```